# Django auto_now_add=True but "received a naive datetime"

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model field as follows with a timezone aware auto add:

`start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)`

However I still get a RuntimeWarning when running tests:

`RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Survey.start_date received a naive datetime (2020-07-16 03:15:14.463640) while time zone support is active.`

I get the same when I have:

`start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you using **`Survey.start_date`** anywhere in your Django code for ***filtering*** the results or ***updating the values***?

Comment: This was my issue - the naive datetime was due to a custom manager filtering on datetime.today() rather than timezone.now().

Comment: @thms would you mind adding your comment as a solution? It's what also solved a problem I had.

Answer (score 2):

This also can be caused by any case where you have custom model manager filtering any date fields on `datetime.today()` rather than `timezone.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem only on tests. It was caused by an old migration that had this operation in it:

```py
migrations.AddField(
    model_name="marketplacelisting",
    name="created_at",
    field=models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        default=datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 7, 15, 42, 15, 944557),
    ),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

Changing default to `datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 7, 15, 42, 15, 944557, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` solved the problem. Check if that makes sense in your case and adjust your old migrations, because tests will run them.

Answer (score -1):

Your second option should be alright. But you should remove `blank=True`, since by providing a default would mean you could send a request without this field.

```
start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Make sure you have run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after you made the change.